# How can i use document get element by id in ejs?

Tags: node.js, ejs

```
<% function messageBox(id)
{
console.log(id);


 var data=document.getElementById('#id');
 console.log(data);

}
%>
```

I have a above function in ejs file and having issue while calling
 this. Its shows an error below:

> document is not defined
>        at messageBox (eval at  (/var/www/html/nodeproject/helloworld/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:464:12),
>    :46:11).

Actually i want to add class on click the function so that i can show
 the popup div. Is there any way to achieve this.

Comment: Why would u wrap client js in ejs tags. Put them in good old fashion script htnl tags